# 90s(?) comic book about a girl who could shapeshift into different animals

Tags: story-identification, comics, shape-shifter

I read this comic in (I think) 2015 but it was way older; somewhere in the late 90s I believe.

It was about a girl who had dark blue hair and could shapeshift into different animals (wolf, gorilla etc.).  It had something to do with the full moon I think. The story took place in 2050 or after that. She also had a younger sister with pink hair who, if I'm not mistaken, wore a yellow shirt.

The cover of the comic was bright pink and had an image of the main character.

Comment: Reminds me of the "Switcher" books by Kate Thompson. But it is a book, no pictures, so I can not tell exactly.

Answer (score 3):

*Lys*, a French-Italian comic published between 2006 and 2008.

Summary from [PlaneteBD](https://www.planetebd.com/bd/soleil/lys/pleine-lune/2659.html), most of the translation from DeepL:

> In the year 2050, the megalopolis called Côtenord, which includes Paris and Brussels, has a record population and the only 4 animal species to have survived: the fly, the cockroach, the mussel and the Chihuahua. Why did this happen? A mystery. [...] Until the day when **a young teenager capable of transforming herself into a mouse, a hawk or a tiger (or something else) on the nights of the full moon**, decides to work on her own modest level against crime.

Cover of the first book, "Full Moon":

[image: black-haired girl laying on a moon, a cat is laying next to her]

---

Remembered from having previously identified it for a French site about forgotten comics ([BD Oubliées, R1759](https://bdoubliees.com/questionsarchives1700.html)).